# javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-axis

We have an Axis2 service running under Tomcat 7. Has anyone seen this
strange exception before?

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,8783]
Message: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
    at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    at omni.web.nms.ws.OmniWebNMSWSStub.fromOM(OmniWebNMSWSStub.java:13816)
    at omni.web.nms.ws.OmniWebNMSWSStub.gettingSlotStatusFor1U(OmniWebNMSWSStub.java:29910)
    at omni.web.nms.rack1u.TimerFor1uRack.getAllSlotDetailsFromDB(TimerFor1uRack.java:354)
    at omni.web.nms.rack1u.TimerFor1uRack.run(TimerFor1uRack.java:119)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.impl.exception.OMStreamingException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,8783]
Message: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.SwitchingWrapper.getElementText(SwitchingWrapper.java:940)
    at javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate.getElementText(StreamReaderDelegate.java:100)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.getElementText(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:100)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.debug.XMLStreamReaderValidator.getElementText(XMLStreamReaderValidator.java:75)
    at omni.web.nms.ws.OmniWebNMSWSStub$ArrayOfString$Factory.parse(OmniWebNMSWSStub.java:5561)
    at omni.web.nms.ws.OmniWebNMSWSStub$GettingSlotStatusFor1UResponse$Factory.parse(OmniWebNMSWSStub.java:25997)
    at omni.web.nms.ws.OmniWebNMSWSStub.fromOM(OmniWebNMSWSStub.java:13789)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Delete the proxy classes. Regenerate them. Do a clean build and try again.

Comment: project cleaned and again run, same thing happens..

Comment: Did you regenerate the proxy classes? This issue usually happens when there is a change in wsdl and the client proxy classes are not in sync with those changes.

Comment: What do think is strange about the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the same issue that i faced when deploying a Service in Axis 2.
add the axis 2 runtime in
Windows>>Preferences> webservice>> Axis2 preferences

and provide the Axis 2 installation directory

this tutorial helped me a lot 
[[http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.ws.axis2.ui.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Fcaxis2tover.html]](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.ws.axis2.ui.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Fcaxis2tover.html%5d)